# Log4Net incubating?

Tags: logging, log4net

What does this mean "incubating"? well i know what the word means but why are the file named as "incubating-log4net-1.2.10.zip" Apache?
Is log4net still under development as the last release was 2006?

Comment: NB [the project graduated in 2007](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/log4net.html) so while the origin of the term is interesting, the presupposition in the question is not correc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically means that it isn't an official Apache project yet. Probably the project is abandoned as it has been in the incubator for so long and there are no new releases. Ask in apache mailing lists to get more information.

Comment: While that might be technically true in terms of what it means in Apache parlance, log4net is about as far from dead as you can get.  If it has, what's the magic replacement that has supplanted it? The fact that there isnt any code churn in this case is mainly due to the fact that it's been the de facto standard for about 5 years.  Or am I missing something, are there any citations for this? (I personally tried to use System.Diagnostics logging at one stage, but even MS itself doesnt do that!)

Comment: I didn't say it is dead. I've said it is abandoned, which is clearly the case as there is no new release since 2006. Today there are better alternatives available like http://www.nlog-project.org/ or the logging component in the Enterprise library.

Comment: Sorry, didnt mean to be confrontational in that sense. I peeked at NLog and it seemed to be a hobby project reimplementation of Log4net that still had bugs (can someone please fill me in though please, maybe with a link to a question assering its superiority relative to log4net :D). The EL stuff is wildly overcomplex compared to log4net (or NLog), although in some cases of course the abstractions in there may be appropriate for a context.

Comment: log4net is still in active development: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/?sortby=date

Comment: @Petoj [This Apache Incubation page](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/log4net.html) says the project stop being an incubating project in 2007. Can you unaccept this answer as it is not and was not factually correct at any time

Comment: @RubenBartelink it a long time ago i compared log4net with nlog but back then i picked nlog and never looked back, the reason for it was that its config files where easier to write and read. log4net might be more advanced in some aspects but none that mattered for me...

Answer (score 4):

log4net is in widespread production use in a huge variety of products, and not dead or beta by any means (and was a reimplementation of the popular log4j framework which has similar ubiquity in the Java world).

Most of the time, use of 'incubating' and 0.xx naming schemes is an oversight more than a 'here be dragons' / 'here be stuff not interesting enough to fight' indicator that one might infer.

In general, the incubating tag means that it's not being formally released as part of a beta/test/release cycle.

UPDATE: [The project is and was *NOT* at the time of asking the question in incubating state, it graduated in 2007](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/log4net.html)